# Removing line breaks from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a big table imported from a CSV file and I believe that it imported a bunch of unnecessary line breaks which are causing errors in my PHP script.

Is there a SQL query I can run that will go through and remove all the line breaks from my table?

Comment: Are the line breaks within a column or whole rows which are nothing but empty columns?  Normally CSV files end rows on line breaks, so it is kind of unlikely that you can get line breaks within your data, but it depends upon your import method.

Comment: Answer: Yes there is. What is your next question?

Comment: Why in the world does your PHP script break when a few white spaces are thrown at it?

Comment: @CadeRoux I think the line breaks are within my data

Comment: @SalmanA I have no idea. I've been having the problem for weeks and I can't seem to pinpoint the error. Sometimes the query works where there are no whitespace or linebreaks but if there are, it doesn't. I can post my query if need be

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
update table1 set col1 = replace(col1, '<br/>', '');
```

`'<br/>'` is the string you want to replace and last parameter is the replacing string

Comment: They aren't HTML line breaks, so I modified the query to UPDATE expansionplugkits SET Cat2 = REPLACE(Cat2, '\r\n', ''); and it says 0 rows affected.

Comment: actually MySQl recognizes the `\r\n` so i used the following query and it worked
`update test_table set name =  replace(name, '\\r\\n', ' ')`

Answer (score -3):

If you are trying to delete the rows where a  was entered then you could try this...

```
    DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`column1`='</br>';
```

Comment: If you were going to delete rows that contained a br then you'd need to do this:  DELETE FROM `table1` WHERE `table1`.`column1`LIKE '%<br/>%';